# mongoose aggregate on a nested array

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, aggregate

I have a schema that has a sub array and each of its elements reference another schema like so:

```
{
 _id: "5fed222d806311ec81d6df23"
 someOtherNestedDoc: {
    _id: "abc",
    someOtherField: 10
 },
 matches: [
   {
      _id: "5fed222d806311ec81d6daf3",
      user: "5fed222d806311ec81d6dcf3",
      probability: 10
   },
   {
      _id: "5fed222d806311ec81d6d1f3",
      user: "5fed222d806311ec81d62cf3",
      probability: 20
   },
 ]
}
```

I want to do a Mongoose aggregate, in which I lookup the user reference for every match, and only project 3 fields for it, 2 are already existing, the third one is the sum of an array of that schema, so that in the end, I have something like this:

```
{
 _id: "5fed222d806311ec81d6df23"
 someOtherNestedDoc: {
    _id: "abc",
    someOtherField: 10
 },
 matches: [
   {
      _id: "5fed222d806311ec81d6daf3",
      user: {
         firstName: "Max",
         lastName: "Mustermann",
         totalExpenses: 100
      },
      probability: 10
   },
   {
      _id: "5fed222d806311ec81d6d1f3",
      user: {
         firstName: "Herbert",
         lastName: "Mustermann",
         totalExpenses: 200
      },,
      probability: 20
   },
 ]
}
```

And the users would look like this:

```
{
  _id: "5fed222d806311ec81d6dcf3",
  firstName: "Max",
  lastName: "Mustermann",
  password: "test",
  expenses: [
    {
      _id: 1,
     price: 50
    },
    {
      _id: 2,
     price: 50
    },
   ]
}

{
  _id: "5fed222d806311ec81d62cf3",
  firstName: "Herbert",
  lastName: "Mustermann",
  password: "test2",
  expenses: [ 
    {
      _id: 3,
     price: 75
    },
    {
      _id: 4,
     price: 125
    },
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `$unwind` deconstruct `matches` array
- `$lookup` with user collection and pass user id in let,

  - `$match` userId condition
  - `$project` to show required fields, get sum of `expenses.price`
- `$unwind` deconstruct `user` array
- `$group` by `_id` and reconstruct `matches` array

```
db.col1.aggregate([
  { $unwind: "$matches" },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "user",
      let: { userId: "$matches.user" },
      pipeline: [
        { $match: { $expr: { $eq: ["$_id", "$$userId"] } } },
        {
          $project: {
            _id: 0,
            firstName: 1,
            lastName: 1,
            totalExpenses: { $sum: "$expenses.price" }
          }
        }
      ],
      "as": "matches.user"
    }
  },
  { $unwind: "$matches.user" },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      matches: { $push: "$matches" }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/0B-hiEMa-5G)

Comment: that generally works well, the only thing is that, if I have other fields besides "matches" in the original document, then these fields are lost. How can I preserve those? I edited the question.

Comment: you can use $first operator with field name look at this [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ige3cTnvgM7)